# Grep files containing two or more occurrence of a specific string

Tags: unix, grep

I need to find files where a specific string appears twice or more.

For example, for three files:

File 1:

```
Hello World!
```

File 2:

```
Hello World!
Hello !
```

File 3:

```
Hello World!
Hello
Hello Again.
```

--

I want to grep `Hello` and only get files `2` & `3`.

Comment: @Melanie Shebel - not really sure what you are looking for. It may be good to know if multiple matches in the same line should be considered or not, for example.

Comment: I have some files that contain "calculation completed" once and some that contain "calculation completed" twice. I need to pull a list of the files that contain the string twice. The strings appear on separate lines.

Comment: Then _all_ of the answers below will work. What more do you need?

Comment: @MelanieShebel ok. Adding a bounty is nice, even though I guess you could have asked a new question to have more control over the possible solutions and desired output.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

What about this:

```
grep -o -c Hello * | awk -F: '{if ($2 > 1){print $1}}'
```

Comment: This will tell us which files contain at least 2 lines containing the word 'Hello'.  What if a file has the line Hello Hello World?  It won't get listed.

Comment: This should be `($2 > 1)` or it will only print file with `3` or more hits.

Comment: @bstar55 Sorry if that was ambiguous. The way the files are designed this issue isn't going to be a problem.

Answer (score 10):

Since the question is tagged `grep`, here is a solution using only that utility and `bash` (no `awk` required):

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *
do
  if [ "$(grep -c "Hello" "${file}")" -gt 1 ]
  then
    echo "${file}"
  fi
done
```

Can be a one-liner:

```
for file in *; do if [ "$(grep -c "Hello" "${file}")" -gt 1 ]; then echo "${file}"; fi; done
```

#### Explanation

- You can modify the `for file in *` statement with whatever shell expansion you want to get all the data files.
- `grep -c` returns the number of lines that match the pattern, with multiple matches on a line still counting for just one matched line.
- `if [ ... -gt 1 ]` test that more than one line is matched in the file. If so:
- `echo ${file}` print the file name.

Answer (score 3):

This `awk` will print the file name of all files with `2` or more `Hello`

```
awk 'FNR==1 {if (a>1) print f;a=0} /Hello/ {a++} {f=FILENAME} END {if (a>1) print f}' *
file2
file3
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need is a `grep` that can recognise patterns across line endings (*"hello" followed by anything (possibly even line endings), followed by "hello"*)

As `grep` processes your files line by line, it is (by itself) not the right tool for the job - *unless* you manage to cram the whole file into one single line.

Now, that is easy, for example using the `tr` command, replacing line endings by spaces:

```
if cat $file | tr '\n' ' ' | grep -q 'hello.*hello'
then
   echo "$file matches"
fi
```

This is quite efficient, even on large files with many (say 100000) lines, and can be made even more efficient by calling `grep` with `--max-count=1` , making it stop the search after a match has been found.  It doesn't matter whether the two hellos are on the same line or not.

Answer (score 1):

After reading your question, I think you also want to find the case `hello hello` in one line. ( `find files where a specific string appears twice or more.`) so I come up with this one-liner:

```
awk -v p="hello" 'FNR==1{x=0}{x+=gsub(p,p);if(x>1){print FILENAME;nextfile}}' *
```

- in the above line, `p` is the pattern you want to search
- it will print the filename if the file contains the pattern two or more times. no matter they are in same or different lines
- during the processing, after checking some line, if we had already found two or more pattern, print the filename and stop processing current file, take the next input file, if there still are. This is helpful if you have big files.

A little test:

```
kent$  head f*
==> f <==
hello hello world

==> f2 <==
hello

==> f3 <==
hello
hello
SK-Arch 22:27:00 /tmp/test
kent$ awk -v p="hello" 'FNR==1{x=0}{x+=gsub(p,p);if(x>1){print FILENAME;nextfile}}' f*
f
f3
```

Comment: Thanks @Kent ! In my specific example I'll never have the string twice in a row, but it's good to know.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
grep Hello * | cut -d: -f1 | uniq -d
```

Grep for lines containing 'Hello'; keep only the file names; print only the duplicates.

Comment: First time I used `-d` switch of `uniq` command!
Interresting!

Answer (score 0):

grep -c Hello * | egrep -v ':[01]$' | sed 's/:[0-9]*$//'

Answer (score 0):

Piping to a scripting language might be overkill, but it's oftentimes much easier than just using `awk`

```
grep -rnc "Hello" . | ruby -ne 'file, count = $_.split(":"); puts "#{file}: #{count}" if count&.to_i >= 2'
```

So for your input, we get

```
$ grep -rnc "Hello" . | ruby -ne 'file, count = $_.split(":"); puts "#{file}: #{count}" if count&.to_i >= 2'

./2: 2
./3: 3
```

Or to omit the count

```
grep -rnc "Hello" . | ruby -ne 'file, _ = $_.split(":"); puts file if count&.to_i >= 2'
```